# Коды русских символов (не в консоли)

Tags: c++

Есть строка, нужно перевести русские символы в ней на аналогичные английские (А на А, В на В, ... , У на Y и тд - всего 12 символов, которые используются в автомобильных номерах).
Проблема в том, что русские символы не распознаются по своему коду, а при попытке получить код символа - код отрицательный. Просто в качестве примера:

```
int russian_upper_y = 147;
char same_russian_upper_y = 'У';
cout << char(russian_upper_y) << " - получение символа по коду"; //выводит "
cout << int(same_russian_upper_y) << "- получение кода по символу"; //выводит -45
cout << same_russian_upper_y << " - вывод символа"; //выводит У
```

Далее в чем проблема:
Если строку инициализируешь сразу после объявления, то коды символов все равно отрицательные, символ по его реальному коду программа не видит.

```
string hello = "привет";
cout << int(hello[0]) << endl;
if (hello[0] == 'п') cout << "один" << endl;
if (int(hello[0]) == 175) cout << "два";
if (int(hello[0]) == -17) hello.replace(hello.find('п'), 1, "L");
cout << hello;
```

Вывод консоли в данном случае выглядит так:

```
-17
один
Lривет
```

Если ту же строку ввожу с консоли c помощью getline(), то получаю на выходе:

```
-81
*а на второй строке рандомный набор символов*
```

Собственно, вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы можно было беспрепятственно заменить некоторые русские символы на похожие по написанию английские и в чем проблема Visual Studio, выводящего отрицательные коды символов?
Как пример того, что нужно сделать:
С клавиатуры вводится номер, пусть У345МО. Мне нужно заменить У на Y и М, О на М, О английские и далее уже искать по базe.

Comment: Кодировка какая? Выводит `-45`, потому что диапазон char: `-128 - 127`

Comment: Используется юникод

Comment: попробуйте поставить unsigned char ( и будут без знака байты ) определите пары которые вам нужны (первые в паре идут 208 и 209 на русском и укр алфавитах), а вторые смотрите сами

Comment: Судя по распечатанным результатам в примере см. [cp-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (а не utf/ucs и т.п. кодировки юникода) / Число отрицательное, поскольку `char` знаковый.  Приводите все к `(unsigned char)`

Comment: забудьте про коды и сравнивайте с символьными константами, как в строке if (hello[0] == 'п') ... Еще лучше, символы, которые ищете и на которые заменяете, запишите в два массива или в две строки, тогда можно в цикле их все заменить и не думать ни про коды, ни про их количество.